# setting tool tip for custom button for rich text editor

Tags: sitecore-client, richtext-editor, custom-field

I have created a custom insert link button by inserting an item based on    `/sitecore/templates/System/Html Editor Profiles/Html Editor Button` in html editor profile rich text editor. It is working fine and meeting all the requirement except that it is not showing the tooltip on hover. I am not sure where to set the tooltip as the above template doesnot have any tooltip field. I can see that there is no title field in the rendered html for that button.
I do not wan to use WebEdit button as in that case I will have to change the existing js files instead of patching the js file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set a display name of your button to whatever you want to be a tooltip:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marek, that saved my day, I thought i will have to manipulate some script or css as I was using the existing insertlink (modified) js for the button.